# Importing files from different folders with Haskell source code

Tags: haskell, cabal

Say I have some folders laid out like this:

```
\Code
    \Haskell
        \euler
            \P1.hs
            \P2.hs
            \P3.hs
        \fermat
            \GS
                \primes.hs
```

There are some functions that I've written in `primes.hs` that I would like to use in `P3.hs`.  Is there a way to load the functions from `primes.hs` into `P3.hs` without just copying and pasting the code, similar to the way you can import modules that are in the same folder?  Can this be done with Cabal (I'm fairly new to Haskell, I haven't had a chance to become familiar with Cabal yet)?  I know there's some way to do it by loading `primes.hs` manually with ghci, but I'd like to just be able to run `P3.hs` and have it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell expects to find the module `Foo.Bar.Baz` in the file `Foo/Bar/Baz.hs`. If you name your modules according to what folder they're in, and you load them with your current working directory at the root of the tree, everything should turn out fine. You don't actually need Cabal just to make that work. (Although as your programs get bigger, it of course becomes quite worth learning Cabal.)

A Haskell file with no module declaration defaults to being called `Main`. To give the correct module name, you need to do something like

```
module Foo.Bar.Baz where
```

at the top of each source file. So, for example, if you start the file `Code/Haskell/Euler/P1` with the declaration

```
module Euler.P1 where
```

and start from a command prompt pointed at `Code/Haskell`, you should be good.

Note that Haskell module names *must* start uppercase. I *believe* (but I'm not 100% certain) that matching against filenames is case-insensitive here. (Because Windows treats filenames as case-insensitive.)

Comment: Going back through my old questions I realized I never actually accepted your answer!  There you go, that's worth a little bit of rep I think.

Answer (score 8):

If you create a `cabal` project this is pretty straightforward.  I would recommend a structure like

```
project-name/
    src/
        Euler/
            P1.hs
            P2.hs
            P3.hs
        Fermat/
            GS/
                Primes.hs
```

Then when you `cd /path/to/project-name`, run `cabal init`, fill in the information as it prompts you, and you're just about set.  The last thing you'll need to do is set up the module names.  A module's name should reflect its location in your `src` folder, and since all module names must start with upper case letters this means you need to make sure your folders are capitalized properly as well.  Here you would have the modules `Euler.P1`, `Euler.P2`, `Euler.P3`, and `Fermat.GS.Primes`.  Declare the module names as `module Module.Name where` in each file as appropriate, and then you can import each from each other as you please.  Module imports are always fully qualified as well, so if you want to import `src/Euler/P1.hs` in `src/Euler/P2.hs`, you would need to do it as `import Euler.P1`

You'll probably run into a few bumps along the way, but using cabal to manage your project is very useful in the long run.  Learn the basics and you'll be setting up projects with ease.